# I am having IF THEN ELSE error using Parameters

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

I have an expression that says:

```
IF (?Quarter Selection? = 'PY 2017 Q3' 
    AND ?Type of Report? = 'Exiter Report') 
THEN ([Seeker Status Date] BETWEEN TO_DATE('10/01/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
    AND TO_DATE('12/31/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')) 
ELSE (1=1)
```

I get a host of errors when I validate it. If I take out one of the parameters in the IF section, it works fine. Example:

```
IF (?Quarter Selection? = 'PY 2017 Q3') 
THEN ([Seeker Status Date] BETWEEN TO_DATE('10/01/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
    AND TO_DATE('12/31/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')) 
ELSE (1=1)
```

Can you not have more than one parameter in the statement?

Comment: How are you sending in the parameters?

Comment: From the Prompt page.

Comment: Can you provide the errors?

Comment: @Johnsonium
- UDA-QOS-0006 Error
- QE-DEF-0459
- RQP-DEF-0177
- UDA-SQL-0358

Comment: I did a Google search for your first error code and Cognos and the first result was this https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21695817. This looks similar to your problem.

Comment: Maybe the statement is too complex for Cognos to convert properly.  Did you try moving away from the Cognos syntax to a statement that is compatible with your RDBMS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to return conditional expressions.

```
[Seeker Status Date] BETWEEN TO_DATE('10/01/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
    AND TO_DATE('12/31/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

and

```
1=1
```

are not values.

Try returning values in the `THEN` and `ELSE` parts of the statement.

Comment: You are wrong. I thought we settled this previously. When it comes to filters, the output of a conditional is itself a condition, not a value. The fact that his syntax works when he restricts it only one parameters should have clued you in.

Comment: @Johnsonium OK, You're right.  We discussed this before.  It just seems like a way to code that will confuse the next maintainer.  Why not write code with clear endpoints like `if (a=b) then (if(c=d) then (TRUE) else (FALSE)) else (TRUE)`?

Comment: Thanks for the insights. This helped me tremendously.

Comment: @dougp Because that's harder for people to understand.